# Chances of denial of entry with a valid visa

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, denial-of-entry

I used to be a student in the US on F-1 visa. I graduated but was not able to secure an employment that would grant me H-1B. Instead I was hired as a private contractor and have no permission to work in the US. Basically I overstayed for slightly over 8 months and out of status now.

My father got a tourist visa to the US on two occasions. Once back in 2005 for 6 months and another one in 2009 for 5 years. He visited me twice and returned to his home country.

He want to visit me for a couple of weeks again in a few months. His tourist visa is valid and he does not have to go to a US embassy.

My questions is what are the chances that he would be denied entry to the US at a point of entry (airport) based on his son's (i.e. mine) immigration status. He is not aware of intricate details of the US immigration law. He knows that I graduated (which is true) and got hired (also true). He doesn't know that I do not have a valid permit to stay in the US.

What should he say if he is asked whom are you visiting and what are the chances they ask or try to verify the immigration status of the person he is visiting ?

Any help/suggestions/recommendations are greatly appreciated.

PS He is not trying to stay in the US. He does have extensive family back home (wife, grand kids, house etc.) and he has air tickets to fly back and the itinerary of our vacation that I have arranged for him and for myself.

Comment: If he is a tourist, he doesn't have to have somebody there. He has to provide a return ticket (if asked at passport control) and accommodation details (hotel reservation perhaps).. but he (as a tourist) is not required to provide contact details in the US..

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a reliable answer to this question, but I think the chances that your father will have any problems is very small if his visa is valid. I've even seen a case in a documentary on US Border Patrol where the person entering the US admitted they were visiting a relative who was staying the US illegally and the border agent didn't seem care or bother reporting it as the person entering had a valid visa. Of course this is all up to the agent's discretion.

Answer (score 4):

Well, tourist visas are issued to *tourists*, tourists do not have to have a contact person/organization at the US. He might be asked to provide a return ticket and/or accommodation details at the customs/passport control.

Anyway, there is a very small chance that they will ask him about you if he put your name as the contact person in the old entries but this is very unlikely.